# str_getcsv returns weird results

Tags: php, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
 1,1,1
 2,2,2
 3,3,3
```

and the following php code:

```
 $row = str_getcsv(file_get_contents($filename));
 print_r($row);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 1
  [2] => 1
  2
  [3] => 2
  [4] => 2
  3
  [5] => 3
  [6] => 3
)
```

Should be:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 1
  [2] => 1
  [3] => 2
  [4] => 2
  [5] => 2
  [6] => 3
  [7] => 3
  [8] => 3
)
```

Any ideas why this is happening? my goal is to read csv in multi-dimensional array. Thanks!

Comment: If your goal is a multi-dimensional array, then your "should be" is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_getcsv` expects *a single line* of CSV input. You must use it like this:

```
$csv  = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$data = array();
foreach ($csv as $line) {
    $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
```

But if you're doing that, you may as well use the more efficient `fgetcsv`:

```
$fh   = fopen($filename, 'r');
$data = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no comma after last 1 and last 2  :)

Answer (score 1):

`str_getcsv` could only parse one line of csv data, not whole.

You could get your result by a loop, or just

```
$row = str_getcsv(join(',', file($filename)));
```

If the format is fixed, you may just use `explode` instead.

Or for a file, there is **[fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)** function.